# Compatibily browsers for <iframe> tag in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, compatibility

on my website, I would like to display another website by using the < iframe > tag. But the problem is that this site only works in Internet Explorer. I would like it to also be compatible with Chrome and/or Mozilla.

Please help if anyone knows how to solve the compatibility issues.

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<iframe 
    src="https://www.santanderwebmortgage.com/" 
height="100%"
width="100%"
frameborder="1"
style="height:500px; width:800px; 
border-width:5px; border-style:solid; border-color:Red;">
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp supported all major browsers

Comment: I have not found anything concrete...

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not a problem describe. Describe what you expect to happen and how behavior on some browsers differs from this. Make sure you give a real example if you want to solve your real problen.

Comment: There is no compatibility issue... if it doesn't work, you're just using it wrong ;) try giving a height in pixel `height="500px"` and not only in the `style` attribute.

Comment: @Pinki — No, that's wrong. The `height` attribute is not CSS and does not take CSS lengths. [The attributes, if specified, must have values that are valid non-negative integers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-dim-height) (integers, not CSS lengths)

Comment: ye sorry `height="500"` my bad, but that's not the problem anyway

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to fool the website somehow that would be compatible in other browsers, even though it made ​​only for IE. Maybe using some userAgents .... but it's something I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with iframes. `https://www.santanderwebmortgage.com/` is browser sniffing and rejecting non-IE browsers. You need to get them to make their website work.

Comment: This is not the right website, I gave only an example. In fact I own a website which I would like to be compatible with other browsers, but it is running on the localhost. Actually goes for the WinCC Web Navigator.

Comment: @user3445399 — Given that the page you've given as an example renders in the iframe (even if that page is just a complaint that you aren't using IE), whatever the problem are with your other page, they are not revealed in your question.

Comment: That WinCC Web Navigator which should be displayed within the <iframe>, I cannot change him... It's actully just like the website that I give for example. So, there isn't any possibility to make website compatible with other browsers?

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible to fool the website somehow that would be compatible in other browsers, even though it made ​​only for IE. Maybe using some userAgents? .... but it's something I do not know how to do.

Comment: If a website browser sniffs and rejects a browser, then the only way you can work around that is to either (1) Fix the website or (2) Make the browser lie about it's user agent (which only the browser controller can do, the author of a third party with site a frame certainly cannot do that) and hope that the site will support it in practise.

Comment: So I can not do anything about it...
Thanks for all Quentin.

Answer (score 0):

As your iframe's height is in percentage which will work only in ie and other browsers would not work. To make this  work you need to define the height of it's parent. For easy apply height in html,body:

```
html,body{
height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is not a problem. Actually this is not the right website. I gave only an example. In fact I own a website which I would like to be compatible with other browsers, but it is running on the localhost. Actually goes for the WinCC Web Navigator.

Comment: That would be too easy. I think I should do something somehow with the userAgents.